# Magento 1.9.1.0 catalog search pagination not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I have problem regarding **catalogsearch** in magento 1.9.1.0. following **catalogsearch.xml**.

```
    <layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms">
            <label>Search Terms</label>
            <url helper="catalogsearch/getSearchTermUrl" />
            <title>Search Terms</title>
        </action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch">
            <label>Advanced Search</label>
            <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
            <title>Advanced Search</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>

<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <label>Quick Search Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result" template="catalogsearch/result.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
            <action method="setListOrders"/>
            <action method="setListModes"/>
            <action method="setListCollection"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
</layout>
```

When I click page number 2 or next button its give **Please Wait..** message but not load more product or not jump to next page.

When I set **page/3columns.phtml** pagination work.

Place help me for this solution..

Comment: You are using any 3rd party module

Comment: No I am using "theme" file only nothing else

Comment: is it paid theme

Comment: yes it paid theme

Comment: it support ajax so disable ajax layer navigation and check it redirect or not

Comment: how can i disable ajax ?

Comment: which theme you are using? check back end theme setting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30022/discussion-between-hardik-and-learning-magento).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable your ajax then it will work but this is not permanent solution may be some js conflict is there please check it